# Accessing a JS UI Component's members from another JS module

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent

I take it we're all accustomed with the omnipresent

```
// js-module1.js
define(
    ['Magento_Module/js/someComponent'],
    function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({property: 123});
    }
);
```

But how can you access members (properties, methods) of the Component *in another JS module* (public access I mean)? For example, another `js-module2.js` requiring the first one:

```
// js-module2.js
define(

    ['Magento_Module/js/js-module1'],

    function (Component) {
        var prop = Component.property; 
        // expecting "123", but it's an error, as Component is a function
    }
);
```

From what I understand, the returned value is actually [this one here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/73a52306e3d11b6818c8920d624bc58597a19dc0/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/class.js#L136-L139), as that's the base "class" of the JS Component, but that code is so confusing right now.

What *is* that thing? Can its members be accessed publicly? Some of the native view models have really nice properties/methods which could help me, but I can't get to them.

Comment: I've not done a lot with Require so take what I say with a pinch of salt, but I think the whole point of Require is to prevent JS from being global/public.

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668293/accessing-variable-from-different-filesmodule-using-requirejs

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me at first. Namely, I thought that, if I have a public property on an exported module, I'm _explicitly_ giving public access to said property. But your link helped me understand that it's wrapped in a function to avoid context pollution. Thanks. That helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm completely sure this is not the way it is desiged to be used, but in module2 you can just do

```
// does not work
var prop = Component.property; 

// works!
var prop = Component.call().property;
```

With the call() you return the very same instance:

```
// js-module1.js

var myGlobalTest;

define(
  ['Magento_Module/js/someComponent'],
  function (Component) {
    myGlobalTest = this;
    return Component.extend({});
}
);
```

.

```
// js-module2.js

define(
    ['Magento_Module/js/js-module1'],

    function (componentToUse) {
        myGlobalTest === componentToUse.call()  // true
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm a Require-JS noob. You've convinced me. Ben Crook, too. Thanks.